How do I resize /dev/sda3 in a Proxmox (Debian) system?
I am new to Linux and new to Proxmox.  I am running Proxmox as a VM under VMWare Workstation Pro (VMW).  When creating this VM I allocated 500GB of host hard drive space to a single virtual drive.  Later, from within VMW, I expanded this virtual drive from 500GB to 700GB.
Just after expanding the VMW virtual disk, I started the Proxmox VM.  From within the VM, lsblk shows this:
root@test:~# lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                            8:0    0   700G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0  1007K  0 part 
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda3                         8:3    0   499G  0 part 
  ├─pve-swap                 252:0    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root                 252:1    0    96G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta           252:2    0   3.8G  0 lvm  
  │ └─pve-data-tpool         252:4    0 371.4G  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-data             252:5    0 371.4G  1 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--100--disk--0 252:6    0    32G  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--101--disk--0 252:7    0     4M  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--101--disk--1 252:8    0   128G  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 252:9    0     4M  0 lvm  
  │   └─pve-vm--102--disk--2 252:10   0     4M  0 lvm  
  └─pve-data_tdata           252:3    0 371.4G  0 lvm  
    └─pve-data-tpool         252:4    0 371.4G  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-data             252:5    0 371.4G  1 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--100--disk--0 252:6    0    32G  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--101--disk--0 252:7    0     4M  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--101--disk--1 252:8    0   128G  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 252:9    0     4M  0 lvm  
      └─pve-vm--102--disk--2 252:10   0     4M  0 lvm  
sr0                           11:0    1  15.6G  0 rom  

The disk sda shows the new MVW virtual disk size of 700GB.  How do I expand sda3 with the ultimate goal of pve-root seeing the added space?
I tried resizing what Proxmox thinks is the physical volume.  I got a warning and I bravely proceeded (the advantage of running Proxmox as a snapshotted VM).  But sda3 remained at 499GB.
root@test:~# pvresize /dev/sda3 --setphysicalvolumesize 700G
  WARNING: /dev/sda3: Overriding real size <499.00 GiB. You could lose data.
/dev/sda3: Requested size 700.00 GiB exceeds real size <499.00 GiB. Proceed?  [y/n]: y
  WARNING: /dev/sda3: Pretending size is 1468006400 not 1046476767 sectors.
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

Yet, nothing has changed:
root@test:~# lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                            8:0    0   700G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0  1007K  0 part 
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda3                         8:3    0   499G  0 part 
  ├─pve-swap                 252:0    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root                 252:1    0   112G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta           252:2    0   3.8G  0 lvm  
  │ └─pve-data-tpool         252:4    0 371.4G  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-data             252:5    0 371.4G  1 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--100--disk--0 252:6    0    32G  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--101--disk--0 252:7    0     4M  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--101--disk--1 252:8    0   128G  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 252:9    0     4M  0 lvm  
  │   └─pve-vm--102--disk--2 252:10   0     4M  0 lvm  
  └─pve-data_tdata           252:3    0 371.4G  0 lvm  
    └─pve-data-tpool         252:4    0 371.4G  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-data             252:5    0 371.4G  1 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--100--disk--0 252:6    0    32G  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--101--disk--0 252:7    0     4M  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--101--disk--1 252:8    0   128G  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 252:9    0     4M  0 lvm  
      └─pve-vm--102--disk--2 252:10   0     4M  0 lvm  
sr0                           11:0    1  15.6G  0 rom  


You need to resize the partition (sda3) first - see this - though, reading some of the answers makes me think not many people know what they are doing :p

I did it twice, the first I screwed myself, but luckily I had a snapshot and could done it on the second time, so remind that's a dangerous action
